# How to filter array data in React js and update the data to useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filter, use-state

i really need help because i still learning about react js and data structure, i want ask about how to filtering spesific array data from redux and push to useState.

```
dataPortfo: [
{
  id: 0,
  title: "Retne Cms",
  link: "www.google.com",
  image: "/images/a1.png",
  category: "website",
},
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Jaramba",
  link: "",
  image: "/images/a1.png",
  category: "website",
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: "Atisiri Quiz Web",
  link: "",
  image: "/images/a2.png",
  category: "website",
},
{
  id: 3,
  title: "Retne Cms",
  link: "www.google.com",
  image: "/images/a1.png",
  category: "mobile",
},
{
  id: 4,
  title: "Retne Cms",
  link: "www.google.com",
  image: "/images/a1.png",
  category: "mobile",
},
```

],

aboove data from redux and i useSelector to get data from redux store.

```js
const datePortfo = useSelector(selectPortfo);
const [kategori, setKategori] = useState("all");
const [filterData, setFilter] = useState([]);
  
  
  const checkKategori = () => {
    if (kategori === "website") {
      console.log("web");
      datePortfo.filter((data) => {
        if (data.category === "website") {
          console.log(data.category);
          setFilter([data]);
        }
      });
    }
    if (kategori === "mobile") {
      console.log("mob");
    }
    if (kategori === "all") {
      console.log("all");
    }

  };
  useEffect(() => {
    checkKategori();

    console.log(filterData);
    // console.log(kategori);
  }, [datePortfo,kategori]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

i want display spesific data based on category, when i try with my code and try to filter the data just display 1 data. pls help meee, thank you guys :) i'm still newbiee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should do that:

```
let filteredData = datePortfo;
if(kategori != "all")
  filteredData  = datePortfo.filter((data) =>  data.category === kategori);

setFilter(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `filter` method creates a copy of the array, which you have to save in a variable. The function which you pass to `filter` is a predicate which has to return either `true` or `false` depending on whether the row is retained or not.
2. The result of `filter` which you saved can be used in `setFilteredData`.